# sql Creating a function that limits by input

Tags: sql, mariadb

Trying to return the total sum of the bottom 3 results if I call the input as 3.  Currently it returns as a dataset which isn't allowed, how would I fix this?

Code looks like

```
DELIMITER++

CREATE FUNCTION function1 (input INT) returns INT
BEGIN
DECLARE amount int;

    SET amount = input;

    SELECT SUM(T.C1*Y.C2) 
    FROM Table T, YTable Y 
    WHERE T.ID=Y.TID 
    ORDER BY T.C1*Y.C2 ASC 
    LIMIT amount;

END++
```

Table T (C1, ID) has values

```
(20,1), (50,2), (100,3), (110, 4)
```

YTable Y (C2, TID) has values

```
(30, 1), (90, 2), (110, 3), (160,4)
```

Expected output would be 20*30 + 50*90 + 100*110
=16,100

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to determinate which are the bottom results.

```
WITH cte as (
     SELECT T.C1*Y.C2 as total, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.C1*Y.C2) as rn
     FROM Table T
     JOIN YTable Y 
       ON T.ID = Y.TID 
)
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= input
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct the query using `CONCAT()`, `prepare` it, and `execute` it.